# How to run Mock-server in parallel with angular tests in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: angular, unit-testing, azure-devops, e2e-testing

I have a pipeline for my angular application. In this pipeline I want to run my unit tests and e2e tests.
The problem is I use a mock-server to simulate the API and I use it for my tests. is there any ways to run the mock server without blocking the pipeline.

This is my pipeline

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master
- develop
- feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build:ssr
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- script: npm run mock-server
  displayName: 'mock-server' 

  
- script: npm run test
  displayName: 'jasmine test'

- script: npm run e2e
  displayName: 'e2e test'
```

Comment: Run it in a container?

Comment: I don't know how will that fix my problem

Comment: Because the container containing your mock-server will run **alongside** your build process. See the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#single-job) for details

Comment: Just as Daniel said, the mock-server runs along with pipeline build process, you cannot avoid the situation. So I am afraid that there is no other way.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers, I will try to put my code in a container, the problem that i might face is that I don't want the mock server to be running when I deploy it.